# How to enable Public API metrics in SonarQube for C# code

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

We are trying to add public API metrics to our SonarQube server:

- **Public documented API (%)**
- **Public undocumented API**

We have our SonarQube server setup, analysis, code coverage and everything is getting metrics correctly, but we are not getting any public API metrics. Anyone knows how to setup the public API metrics for C# or is this not supported yet by the Sonar C# plugin?

*Enviroment:*

- SonarQube Server 6.2
- Sonar C# 5.9
- Sonar MSBuild Scanner 2.2
- Jenkins 2.46.1

*References:*

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Metric+Definitions

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp